Is Occam’s razor the basis of induction? Can it “solve” the problem of induction?
I asked a similar question in regards to theory choice but I feel as if this one may be more pertinent.
If one notices a certain pattern in data, is it not simpler to posit that the pattern will continue tomorrow than to not?
For if the pattern continues tomorrow, tomorrow’s data can still be compressed within the law that defines the pattern. If the series of data can be represented by initial conditions and laws, then data fitting that pattern tomorrow would still be completely represented by those very same initial conditions and laws.
If not, the pattern will break, and thus future data cannot be represented by that pattern. Sure, future data along with past data may be represented by an even simpler pattern, but we have no reason to think this until such pattern materializes.
Either way, does this not give atleast some level of reasonable justification to believe in the continuance of a pattern without presupposing the past pattern which seems to be the main contention under the problem of induction?

See Ockham’s Razor: Ockham’s metaphysical views are thought to stem from an underlying concern for ontological parsimony as summed up in the famous slogan known as “Ockham’s Razor” according to which one “must not multiply entities beyond necessity”.

It is a metaphysical view, grounded in human preference for simple patetrns and explanations. This does not mean that the "simpler" explanation is the corerct one: see e.g. Quantum Mech, that is not simple at all.

I kind of really hate "Occam's Razor". Occam didn't come up with it, Occam didn't popularize it, Occam wasn't historically known for it until long after his death, and the crude approximate heuristics that Occam and his contemporaries had to use since mathematical statistics hadn't been discovered yet have no further use, since an easily memorized formalization now exists. One might as soon refer to Pascal's Heliocentrism as an authority on planetary motion.

How about the law of parsimony? @gs Either way, I would argue we all use the razor, knowingly or unknowingly, to dismiss an infinite number of theories that make unneeded assumptions (such as 800 invisible green goblins working together to make you type). The minimum description length principle in computer science is a neat way of codifying this: to explain is to compress data more than what is currently known. If the proposed theory does not compress data, it is hardly useful to call it an explanation and should be dismissed.

@syed It tracks something true and if you didn't have anything better, you could use it. You don't need it because there now exists a different tool readily to hand that does the exact same thing but better. If you struggle with algebra, Occam's Razor may still be useful to you, but only because you aren't able to use the better tool.

What tool are you talking about? @gs

Bayes' theorem as linked.

@gs Bayes’ theorem is not orthogonal to the razor. The minimum description length principle that I just stated is used by many Bayesians to compute a prior probability of a theory which is effectively a formulation of the razor.

Naive uniformity is the basis of induction if it exists...

@DoubleKnot: There is no uniform distribution over a countably infinite set. If you allow every possible theory and try to assign them all equal probability, then the math doesn't work.

@Kevin uniformity here is in strict sense as universality not in terms of probability or Solomonoff, also notice that I chose the "naive' qualifier in the same way as naive set theory...

@DoubleKnot: I do not understand how you propose to use Bayes' theorem in a context that doesn't conform to the Kolmogorov axioms (which already prove that countably infinite uniform distributions don't make sense). You cannot simultaneously claim that you're going to use a specific mathematical tool, and also disclaim the axioms which that tool is based on. It's one or the other.

@Kevin you're talking past me, please refer wikipedia's problem of induction for my colloquial meaning of uniformity as also employed by Hume there: but by positing a "necessary connection" that depends on the "uniformity of nature"...

@DoubleKnot: Then you mean "naive uniformity" in the sense that "what happened yesterday will probably happen tomorrow," and not in a way that is at all connected with naive set theory. Fine, but that's just Occam's razor in a funny hat.

@Kevin if that’s really the case, you should pay me 200 bucks since perceiving fun is quite a rare commodity nowadays…

I would agree that an assumption of uniformity is the basis of induction. For much of nature, abrupt transitions are uncommon and induction is just a matter of identifying the formula and extending the plot. For the exceptions, we discover that doesn't work and substitute a more complicated model. The razor only says not to complicate unnecessarily, not that doing so is never necessary, and only says preferred, not more correct.

You can get out of circularity with an a priori assertion, which might solve Hume's problem of induction on a bare technicality, since Hume put the problem in terms of circularity: "All experimental reasoning assumes the resemblance of the future to the past, and so cannot prove it without being circular." But the Munchhausen Trilemma always gets you in the end. For the uniformity principle, it just gets you sooner rather than later.
To the specific question:
We can observe that more recent pasts have been like more distant pasts. One of the ways that more recent pasts have been like more distant pasts is by comporting with the laws of statistics which Occam's Razor approximates. But this doesn't help us. To say that Occam's Razor will, in the future, describe the relationship between what is then the recent past (i.e. currently our less distant future) and what is then the more distant past (i.e. already our past) is just a more specific claim about the way that the future will be like the past.
That which has not yet been has not yet been like anything. Consequently no observation of how things have been in the past, including their comportment with Occam's Razor, can let us reason that the future will be like the past... unless we have already asserted that the future will be like the past in the way that it comports with Occam's Razor.

Quote is from the Project Gutenberg translation of Hume's Enquiries here.

For the kind of circularity that you describe, such as  predicting things like the weather, as the OP says with the "today, tomorrow" idea, I don't understand why circularity is a problem. You don't have to solve all the problems of physics to predict the weather, or other practical things. These sort of 'ultimacy' issues only arise when people try to reason beyond what is justified. So why do they do that? "When all else fails, lower your expectations."

@ScottRowe the point of recognizing that metaphisical commitments are statements of faith isn't that you can now go around eating rocks and writing bad checks. Recognizing your own metaphysical commitments to be statements of faith, you can entertain different metaphysical commitments and see whether they make better sense of the world without feeling like you're rejecting reason - or at least have more compassion for other people with different metaphysical commitments and avoid making a fool of yourself by asserting that they must have rejected reason in order to hold them.

Ok, thank you, that's a helpful statement. I think I haven't explicitly thought of that before. If you wish to know how I would respond, it is that because I have no faith or metaphysical commitments anymore but used to, I can have compassion for everyone. And, that no one has lost or rejected reason because it is not how humans think. I am sorry if my comment / question was unclear. I just wonder why people try to reason about ultimates.

Your reasoning seems logical, but it is flawed. The "pattern materialization" you say, is done inside our perception, NOT in nature. What we see in nature is what we measure, so ... in a way ... what we pre-suppose to happen. For example, if I live in earth and I count only planets, then everything is respresented by 0's and 1's: i.e. it is either a planet or not ... and this pettern continues forever until another planet crashes with earth: number 2. If I start counting properly, I find more and more numbers ... and trillions of cells in a human body and if I continue inside the atom, then the numbers are blurred with interference patterns and by going on, with nothingness. What we see is what we measure or what we identify, not the thing per se. The problem of induction is a term describing exactly this : the inability to identify the thing per se, it's roots are in the subjectivity of perception, it is the experiential problem of being a living being. The interrelations of things is so complex, that pattern recognition can only be seen as an abstraction, it is a loss of information, it is like the sense of touch for a blind person, to see...

This is hard to parse through or perhaps I’m too lazy. This should be made clearer in my opinion
